# How to replace partial text on a TextView?

Tags: android

I have a text in a textview which says "you have 60 seconds left in the final lap".I am planning to do a countdown starting from 60 and just want to replace the number portion of the textview without refreshing the entire thing.I know I will be using the CountDownTimer to achieve the countdown but how do I change the text partially. Another way of doing this would be having three textviews to show the static text and use one of them to show the countdown text.Is there a cleaner way of doing this!

Comment: Since only the seconds change which is always in the same place.. use substring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there is not need to update a partial String. Just change the whole content.

If your string is localized,

```
<string name="my_message">text, %1$d! other tex.</string>

String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.my_message), number_of_seconds);
```

and then

```
 textView.setText(text);
```

or, as mentioned by @Gaetan Maisse:

```
String text = res.getString(R.string.my_message, number_of_seconds)
```

Comment: There is even faster : `String text = res.getString(R.string.my_message, number_of_seconds)` ;)

Comment: Thanks its too late in the night asking these type of questions.But I guess there is never a stupid question.On a side note I asked this because I had this notion in my mind that doing a countdown would refresh the text and make it blink.